# How can mobile browser change screen.width?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I'm trying to make a mobile website, able to hold youtube iframe embeds. 
The html has the viewport meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

I'm trying to add this functionality: if the embed's width is larger than screen.width, then resize the embed to fit the screen.

It works great on iOS and Android 4.0, but I'm having problems with Android 2.3.5 on Samsung Galaxy S2, (default browser). On this device, at resize event, when I alert screen.width, the event calls 2 times : first the good value is dispatched, then a bad value (bigger) is dispatched.

Anybody knows something about this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

strange - but since you know the first event has the "good values" you can set a timer to hold them for a second or two.  that way if the values are 0 go ahead and set them and call `var t=setTimeout(resetViewportValues,2000);` otherwise the values were already set correctly so do nothing.

in the `resetViewportValues()` function be sure to set the width and height back to 0 and also  `clearTimeout(t);`

hope that helps